# Android: Master/Detail Flow with different Detail Activities

Tags: android, master-detail

how can I change the Activity/Fragment shown in DetailFragment. Example: In the ListView I have several options the user can chose from. When choosing an option, a detail information will be shown, User Information = XML that has the detail information about the user; Configuration = XML that has the detail information about the configuration; Image = XML that has information to show a image...

each XML has it's own layout, activity and fragment java. But how change from one to another, when the user selects from list?

Greetings and thanks for the help

EDIT:
For anybody who has a similar issue, here my solution:
I have found this tutorial: http://www.michenux.net/android-fragment-swapping-325.html and it helped me to get my app to work.

I have now a masterFragment, which is a listView and is the main menu for the app. In the detailFragment I change up to 10 different layouts, based on selection from menu. Thank to the before mentioned tutorial, it is working perfect.